# technical comparison between the differences in html of jquery mobile and webapp-net

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile-application, webapp-net

I am trying to build an application for smart phone devices. I have searched a lot over the web and I found some good toolkits, These are the toolkits I am considering to work with. Jquery Mobile and webapp-net.

The only problem is I need to kknow about the technical differences in html of these two toolkits. so if you please help me.

BTW this is my second account here, with my previous account i cant not ask any questions here, I want to know what are the reasons to close someones account, I am only here because I need help, and I dont want to waste anyones time. I come here to ask a question and then, some one comes and just does something to my account and I dont even know why they do that. So what is the point of this website if you close some ones account???

Comment: Your question is vague and shows little research. The "technical differences" in the HTML can be seen by *looking at the HTML*. Your last account might have been closed for asking too many questions with similar problems. You should read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for advice on using SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When consider Jquery Mobile and webapp-net, JM is elder and is coming from rich and stable family, that never ment webapp is poor, but you have much recourses and help from the net if u start ur work with JM.

Comment: I have already read about these 2, and I understand they both use HTML, with JS and CSS. BUt the main question remains what is the technical differences between html in JQM, and webapp. it is the same html or is it different??